# Excel COUNTIFS formula not calculating, but works when manually triggered

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I am using Openxml to generated a spreadsheet.

I have various Excel cells with COUNTIFS formulas that are not getting calculated when I generate the Excel spreadsheet using C#, but nothing is wrong with the formulas themselves - Excel isn't recognizing my string as a formula. The reason I know this is that if I select the cell and hit enter on the formula field, it calculates the value.

What my COUNTIFS is doing is only counting if a "check mark" is present on a cell interval and if it matches a string and gives a percentage as a result. An example of the formula is this:

> =COUNTIFS(C9:C10,B16,D9:D10,"✓")/D12

However, I couldn't send double quotes from my code, it would cause an error with the formula, so my solution was to use Excel's UNICHAR function. My generated formula is this:

> =COUNTIFS(C9:C10,B15,D9:D10, UNICHAR(10003))/D12

For some reason, Excel does not automatically calculate the formula even though there is nothing wrong with it.

I have a similar formula that works - it is only processing the cells that have a value bigger than zero.

> =COUNTIFS(C9:C22,B35, D9:D22, CONCATENATE(CHAR(62), CHAR(48)))/COUNTIF(D9:D22, CONCATENATE(CHAR(62), CHAR(48)))

Again, the formula follows my same issue of not being able to send double quotes, but chars 62 and 48 are >0 respectively. This works fine. Excel calculates it.

Now, if I change my data input to put a "v" instead of a check mark on the cells and do

> =COUNTIFS(C9:C10,B15,D9:D10, CHAR(118))/D12

the formula works. This tells me issue is with UNICHAR, for some reason using this function makes excel not auto calculate it.

Has anyone experienced something like this?

From a code perspective, I've tried doing

```
spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties = new CalculationProperties()
{
    ForceFullCalculation = true,
    FullCalculationOnLoad = true
};

spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
```

with no success.

Kinda stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I went back to this and figured out a solution.

I changed the cell font to wingdings and now character 252 is a checkmark, so I was able to use

```
=COUNTIFS(C9:C10,B15,D9:D10, CHAR(252))/D12
```

instead of

```
=COUNTIFS(C9:C10,B15,D9:D10, UNICHAR(10003))/D12
```

and the formula is now calculating properly.